# Swift - Multiple TableView checkmark - save and load choice

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, multi-select

Im trying to save and load choice from TableView Multiple checkmarks.

I have a code ready, but I don't know how to save the selection. And how to load the selection at the opening of the list.

**MY CODE:**

```
var selectedCells = [IndexPath]()
var selectedAreas = [String]()
var Areas = [] //my text for the cells..



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return Areas.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = Areas[indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryType = selectedCells.contains(indexPath) ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    selectedCells.append(indexPath)

    if selectedCell?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
        if let indexremove = selectedAreas.firstIndex(of: (Areas[indexPath.row])) {
            selectedAreas.remove(at: indexremove)
        }

        selectedCell?.accessoryType = .none
        print(selectedCells)
        print(selectedAreas)
        print("remove ")
        selectedCells = selectedCells.filter {$0 != indexPath}

    } else {
        print(selectedCells)
        print(selectedAreas)
        print("add")

        selectedAreas.append(Areas[indexPath.row])
        selectedCell?.accessoryType = .checkmark

    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to do it would be to save an identifier for the cell (for example the indexPath) as an array of selected indexPath in UserDefaults and retrieve them. It not the ideal solution by far though since it assumes that the index paths are always the same and the underlying data model never changes.

Comment: I would be very happy if you could help me and change it on my code please.

Comment: Very fishy, same question been asked from different account 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57973633/multiple-tableview-checkmark-selections-not-working-correctly/57973787#57973787

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use multiple arrays as data source. That's pretty bad practice and inefficient.

Delete them

```
var selectedCells = [IndexPath]()
var selectedAreas = [String]()
```

Declare `Area` as struct and add an `isSelected` member

```
struct Area {
    let name : String
    var isSelected : Bool

    init(name : String, isSelected : Bool = false) {
        self.name = name
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}

var areas = [Area(name: "Foo"), Area(name: "Bar")]
```

In `cellForRowAt` assign the checkmark depending on `isSelected`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let area = areas[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = area.name
    cell.accessoryType = area.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}
```

In `didSelectRow` toggle `isSelected` and reload the row (yes, only two lines of code)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    areas[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

You get the selected areas with

```
let selectedAreas = areas.filter{$0.isSelected}
```

and an array of the names

```
let selectedAreaNames = areas.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
```

To load and save the names to `UserDefaults` add these two methods

```
func saveSelection()
{
   let selectedAreaNames = areas.filter{$0.isSelected}.map{$0.name}
   UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedAreaNames, forKey: "selectedNames")
}

func loadSelection()
{
   guard let selectedAreaNames = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "selectedNames") as? [String] else { return }
   for (index, area) in areas.enumerated() {
      areas[index].isSelected = selectedAreaNames.contains(area.name)
   }
   tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you very much for the help!!
Just a question, how to save the selection to UserDefault, and load it from there?

Comment: You can save the names of the selected items.

Comment: I realised. How do I make the selection (selectedAreas) appear as a list mark?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: I want to save the selection with userdefault, so that after opening the app the selection will appear as a list mark

Comment: As I said save `selectedAreaNames`. On launch load the array and in a loop set the `isSelected` member of the corresponding items and reload the table view.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.
Can you please show me?

How to set the isSelected member of the corresponding...

Comment: @vadian how it is possible with search array?

Comment: In this case I’d suggest to use a class rather than a struct. Classes are reference types.